# How can I use navigation and load a view programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift right now and trying to program a small app.

I am trying to push a view to a webview using navigation. But right now it does not move at all, here is my code:

At the table view where I tap on each cell will let me go to other view:

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var myTable: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["Date Picker","List of Data","Slider","Show Image", "Web Display"];

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSLog("Hello World at console");
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "ListCell", bundle: nil)
    myTable?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        var goView = DatePickerViewController(nibName: "DatePickerViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goView, animated: false)
        println(items[indexPath.row])
        break
    case 1:
        var goView = DetailViewController(nibName: "DetailViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goView, animated: false)
        println(items[indexPath.row])
        break
    case 2:
        var goView = SliderViewController(nibName: "SliderViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goView, animated: false)
        println(items[indexPath.row])
        break
    case 3:
        var goView = ImageCalleryViewController(nibName: "ImageCalleryViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goView, animated: false)
        println(items[indexPath.row])
        break
    case 4:
        // var goView = WebDisplayViewController(nibName: "WebDisplayViewController", bundle:nil)
        // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goView, animated: false)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(WebDisplayViewController(), animated: false);
        println(WebDisplayViewController());
        println(items[indexPath.row])
        break
    default:
        return;

    }
}
```

And here is my code at web view. I am trying not to use Interface Builder (want to get used to the syntax first)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class WebDisplayViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var webView = UIWebView (frame: CGRectMake(20, 240, 280, 310));
        var url = NSURL(string :"http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/Application_Fundamentals/Web_Services/");
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true;
        webView.loadRequest(request);
        self.view.addSubview(webView);
        println("I am in Web");
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

The code in AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let mainVC = ViewController()
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationVC;
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Is your controller with the table view embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: No sir... I thought I am wrong at the webView!

Comment: You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" to understand the basic concepts of how view controllers are used.

Comment: But before this, in the obj C project, I did the same thing, but it worked 
SeeAndDoDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SeeAndDoDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SeeAndDoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];               
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

I don't really understand what you mean by embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: If that worked, the controller where that code was had to be embedded in a navigation controller. If your table view controller at issue in this question is not embedded in a navigation controller, then you can't do a push.

Comment: I add these code in the appDelegate but now the entire screen become dark, does not display the table like the first time anymore:

        let mainVC = ViewController()
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: it seems after I embedded the navigation controller, it does not load any method in the table view anymore. Could you please explain me why? thanks a lot

Comment: I can't tell you anything without knowing what your controller hierarchy is. I have to know what controllers you have, what order they're in, and how you go from one to the next. Embedding a table view controller in a navigation controller should not affect how it works.

Comment: I have a view that display a table. Then I just add the navigation controller to the appDelegate. It show the navigation bar but the screen now is black, it does not show table. It does not even run through the table functions. I don't know why it is like that. :(

Comment: Is it because something wrong with the way I load the table view?

Comment: Post the code you're using in the app delegate.

Comment: Where are you making ViewController's view? In a storyboard? If so, you need to create it with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, not ViewController().

Comment: Yes, i make ViewController's view in storyboard.

Comment: And honestly asking where I put this? I am so new to this...thanks for helping again